# What does CC refer to when describing an engine?

Tags: engine

I have been learning about various older cars on Wikipedia. I've always wondered what the "cc" refers to in the engine description. For example:

- 1964–1969 Porsche 911: 1991 cc
- 1965-1969 Porsche 912: 1582 cc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 cc = 1 cubic centimeter (volume of displacement)

1000 cc = 1 L, so a 2 Liter car is about 2,000 cc (the liters may be rounded when reported)

Some American cars are listed in ci or cid (cubic inches of displacement). 1L = 61.02 cid, so the Ford '5.0L engine' is their 302 cid engine.

Since cars engines typically total well over a liter, they aren't often marketed in ccs. Motorcycle and smaller motors aren't, however, so cc figures like 500cc, 600cc or 900cc are more common.

See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_displacement#Units_of_measure) on Engine Displacement units of measure for more details.

Answer (score 6):

[Cubic centimetre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_centimetre)

It's the amount of displacement of the engine

[image]

One complete cycle of a four-cylinder, four-stroke engine. The volume displaced is marked in orange.

Comment: Do you mean "displacement"? So if I understand correctly, it's the same thing as when they say a "2.0 Liter engine" only in this case for the Porsche 911 it's 1.991 Liter engine?

Comment: Exactly. You will find it used with smaller displacement engines (something less than a liter displacement) or older engine descriptions. With newer engine descriptions they tend to just round the numbers, so "1991cc" becomes "2l" or "2.0l".

Comment: @Andrew Yes Displacement lol. It was late when I wrote that. :)

Comment: This may be out of topic but if I understand correctly the figure, by altering the route of the cylinders you can change (increase or decrease) the volume displaced. Is this correct?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z No, displacement is simply the volume of air pumped through the engine in one complete cycle.

Comment: I know that a similar procedure (changing the route of the pistons) is used in order to gain few cc especially in big engines. For example, a 3.8L engine could be reach 4.2L by this method.

Comment: In the muscle car days, hotrodders would "bore and stroke" an engine. Boring meant to enlarge the cylinder diameters and use oversized pistions (up to 0.040 inch.) Stroking an engine meant re-machining the crankshaft arms to increase the stroke distance of the pistons.